# Calling an extension from the host app

Tags: ios, objective-c, share, ios8, ios-app-extension

So I'm writing an app to demo a share extension that I've written, but I'm not quite sure how to display the extension menu like in the photos app. I have this code which I got off the reference website, but it's not displaying anything.

```
NSExtensionContext *context = [[NSExtensionContext alloc] init];
[self beginRequestWithExtensionContext:context];
```

Is there any other things I need to do besides passing in my input items?

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow the [guide over on Apple's website](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ShareSheet.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH12-SW1). I'm not sure if what you want is a share extension, action extension, or photo editing extension. In each case, you need to specify the `NSExtensionPointIdentifier` and/or `NSExtensionAttributes` in your plist file.

If you had created an extension template from Xcode 6, it should automatically configure this for you.

Answer (score 0):

May be help you.
Apple provides sample code for **ImageInverter: [Creating Action Extensions](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/samplecode/ImageInverter/History/History.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014584-RevisionHistory-DontLinkElementID_1)**

There are concept for Action Extensions.